# Date is Echoing without 'echo' command - php

Tags: php

I have a form that is updated yearly, so a user inputs a date and other information then submits the form which gets stored in a database. When they come back a year later they do the same to overwrite the old records, the problem is is that when they come back the old date is being Echoed, which shouldn't happen. All of the other fields are blank which should happen. I'm not calling for the date to be echoed in the code but it still is.

Code for defining the date pulldown

```
// parameters: $fname - main name of field
//             $date - actual date value from database
//             $beginYear - first value in year list
//             $endYear - last value in year list
//     return: none
function make_date_pulldown($fname, $date, $beginYear, $endYear)
{
  // read the date and break it up into $Year, $Month and $Day
  // so that we can set the "SELECTED" in the option list
  if ($date == ""){
    // set some default values to be safe
$Year = 0;
$Month = 0;
$Day = 0;
} else {
$Year = (int) substr($date,0,4);
$Month = (int) substr($date,5,2);
$Day = (int) substr($date,8,2);
}

// need to build a table around these guys so that there won't
// be any word wrap... it's going to be a 1 row by 5 cols.
echo "<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";

// build month list
echo "  <td><font class=bluetext face=verdana,arial size=-2>\n";
echo "  <center>Month<br>\n";
echo "<select name='month_$fname'>\n";
echo "  <option value='00'></option>\n";
for ($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
printf ("  <option value='%02d'",$i);
if ($i == $Month) {
  printf (" SELECTED");
}
printf (">%02d</option>\n",$i);
}
echo "</select>\n";
echo "  </center>\n";
echo "  </td>\n";

echo "  <td><font class=bluetext face=verdana,arial size=-2>\n";
echo "/";
echo "  </td>\n";

// build day list
echo "  <td><font class=bluetext face=verdana,arial size=-2>\n";
echo "  <center>Day<br>\n";
echo "<select name='day_$fname'>\n";
echo "  <option value='00'></option>\n";
for ($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
printf ("  <option value='%02d'",$i);
if ($i == $Day) {
  printf (" SELECTED");
}
printf (">%02d</option>\n",$i);
}
echo "</select>\n";
echo "  </center>\n";
echo "  </td>\n";

echo "  <td><font class=bluetext face=verdana,arial size=-2>\n";
echo "/";
echo "  </td>\n";

// build year list
echo "  <td><font class=bluetext face=verdana,arial size=-2>\n";
echo "  <center>Year<br>\n";
echo "<select name='year_$fname'>\n";
echo "  <option value='0000'></option>\n";
for ($i=$beginYear;$i<=$endYear;$i++){
printf ("  <option value='%d'",$i);
if ($i == $Year) {
  printf (" SELECTED");
}
printf (">%d</option>\n",$i);
}
echo "</select>\n";
echo "  </center>\n";
echo "  </td>\n";

echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
}
```

Code for the PHP form on the website

```
<u>Date Of Submittal</u><br>
<?php
$startYear  =   date("Y")-1;
$endYear    =   date("Y")+1;
make_date_pulldown("submitdate", $submitdate, $startYear, $endYear);
?>
```

Comment: Please show us all the content of `make_date_pulldown` function.. As I can see this is not all of its content

Comment: Are you sure the second code you posted is the only responsible code to echo the function result? I can't see any output related code here...maybe it is somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @Ryeboflaven Could you supply the full code of make_date_pulldown()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to create a drop down menu based on year ....

```
$date = new DateTime();

//Years
echo makeSelect($date->format("Y")-1, $date->format("Y")+1,$date->format("Y"));

//Month
echo makeSelect(1, 12,$date->format("m"));

//Day
echo makeSelect(1, $date->format("t"),$date->format("d"));
```

Function Used

```
function makeSelect($start, $end, $default = null) {
    $content = "<select>";
    $range = range($start, $end);
    $selected = "";
    foreach ( $range as $value ) {
        $selected = ($default == $value) ? "selected" : null;
        $content .= sprintf('<option value="%s" %s>%1$s</option>', $value, $selected);
    }
    $content .= "</select>";
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: The dropdown functionality works fine and stores information fine. The problem is that it is echoing the information from the database and I don't want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, in my get_() function to call the database table I was reading the row for the submitdate and it was pulling and displaying the date based on that command and the function for make_date_pulldown.

Here is what that function looked like (obviously trimmed down):

```
<?
function get_submit($id, &$submitdate)
{                                                             
$query = "select * from submit where id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);                              
if ($result) {                                              
$total_rows = mysql_numrows($result);                     
} else { $total_rows = 0; }                                 
if ($total_rows > 0) {                                      
$submitdate = trim(mysql_result($result, "", "submitdate"));
} else {
$submitdate = "";
$found = 1;
}            
}              
?>
```